# Center nav and span width of page

Tags: html, css

Trying to place nav center of page and take up enter width. I found several pages that suggest to add display inline-block but that does not work. I've also tried setting the width of the nav to 100% which also does not work. I also tried setting the margin-right and margin-left to auto. Thank you.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/centem/pen/BaajLZm

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0 auto;  
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  font-family: monospace;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

ul {
  background: rgb(67, 66, 66);
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgb(67, 66, 66);
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

li a {
  color: #fff;
}

li:hover,
li:focus-within {
    background: rgb(0,0,0);
    cursor: pointer;
}

li:focus-within a {
  outline: none;
}

ul li ul {
    background: rgb(67, 66, 66);
    visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  min-width: 5rem;
    position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  margin-top: 1rem;
    left: 0;
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover > ul,
ul li:focus-within > ul,
ul li ul:hover,
ul li ul:focus {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block
}

ul li ul li {
    clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flex` to make you content to the center. Also, the floats need to be cleared for the content to come to the next line. Below is the refactored code.

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  font-family: monospace;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

ul {
  background: rgb(67, 66, 66);
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgb(67, 66, 66);
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

li a {
  color: #fff;
}

li:hover,
li:focus-within {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
}

li:focus-within a {
  outline: none;
}

ul li ul {
  background: rgb(67, 66, 66);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  min-width: 5rem;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover>ul,
ul li:focus-within>ul,
ul li ul:hover,
ul li ul:focus {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block
}

ul li ul li {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

section {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a>
      <ul>
        <li href="#">One</li>
        <li href="#">Two</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a>
      <ul>
        <li href="#">One</li>
        <li href="#">Two</li>
        <li href="#">Three</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<section>
  <div class="section-header">
    <span>One</span>
    <span>Two</span>
    <span>Three</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
</section>

<footer>
</footer>
```

Comment: I have the nav set to flex and clear: both but still it does not center. What else is missing? Thank you.

Comment: did you copy the above code correctly? this is the change made -> `nav {
  font-family: monospace;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}`

Comment: like, can you just update the codepen and then share the link? if you ask me `Why does width: 100% not work?` I am not sure of what the context is.

Comment: Oh I see. I had to also use justify-content and the nav is stretching but I did not give it a background color. Thanks.